# Zend route regex for one character in url

Tags: regex, zend-framework, url-rewriting, zend-route

For an web-application i need to handle the following url structure:

http://foo.tld/a/foo

I need to write a regex for my route to handle /a/ this part has to contain only 1 character as possibility.

I handle now with:

```
routes.suggestions.type = "Zend_Controller_Router_Route_Regex"
resources.router.routes.suggestions.route = ":character/:q"
resources.router.routes.suggestions.defaults.module = "default"
resources.router.routes.suggestions.defaults.controller = "index"
resources.router.routes.suggestions.defaults.action = "search"
resources.router.routes.suggestions.defaults.character = ""
```

But if conflict with other controller urls such as '/ajax/index' because I overwrite it now.

Can someone help me to place a regex on the route above to make ':character' just available for one single character?

Regards,
Nick

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding this line:

```
resources.router.routes.suggestions.reqs.character = "\w"
```

That will add the regex `\w` (match 1 character a-z) to the `:character` parameter in the URL.  If you add that, it will only route to `SearchController` if the URL parameter before the `:q` is 1 character long.

See also [Using Zend_Config with the RewriteRouter](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.controller.router.html#zend.controller.router.add-config).